# Auth::guard() not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php
return [
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'user',
    'passwords' => 'user',
],
'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => 'App\User',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => 'App\Admin',
    ],
],
'passwords' => [
    'user' => [
        'provider' => 'user',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'provider' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ]
]
];
?>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/test1', function() {
   return Auth::guard('admin');
});

Route::get('/test2', function() {
   return Auth::guard('user');
});
```

**and here's the error I'm getting**

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\storage\framework\compiled.php on line 11193 and defined

what's wrong ?

Comment: take a look at this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-error-missing-argument-1-for-illuminateauthauthmanagercreatedriver?page=1

Comment: `php artisan optimize`didn't work ... !? what does he mean when he says (*Maybe just delete **the file** and then `artisan optimize`*) ?

Answer (score 1):

Example with: table name is admins. model name is Admin.your guard name is admins.

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins'
    ]
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class
    ]        
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ]        
],
```

];